# Akaike information criterion for categorical and numerical data

Tags: feature-selection, aic, intuition

How should I compute [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) for categorical and for numeric variables in classification problems?

I see in Chapter 6 of [Zumel and Mount](http://www.manning.com/zumel/) that they use [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) before they train classification algorithms (trees, logistic regression, kNN) on a classification problem with both categorical and numerical features. They compute AIC as $2\,\left(\log L- \log L_{base}\right)-2^S$ for categorical variables, and  $2\,\left(\log L- \log L_{base}\right)-1$ for numeric variables ($L$ is likelihood, $L_{base}$ is likelihood of the saturated model, $S$ is entropy). They keep features with AIC above a certain threshold, which presumably can be modified to improve algorithm performance.

The choice of $2^S$ seems odd: my intuition tells me that $2^S$ should scale as $L$, not $\log L$. Also, why does entropy enter one and not the other? Could someone provide an explanation, or references justifying this choice? Intuition vs equation is highly appreciated!